# shorthand for [:alpha:] in python regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode

What is equivalent of `[:alpha:]` if I am making a unicode regex that need it.

For example for `[:word:]` it is `[\w]`

will be great if I get some help.

Comment: `\w` is alphanumeric and `_`

Comment: @jamylak Thats true but I was wondering for shorthand for [:alpha:] as \w is for [:word:]. Wonder if it exists at all.

Comment: why do you keep saying `\w` is for `[:word:]`

Comment: @jamylak: According to RegexBuddy, `[[:word:]]` matches `_`.

Comment: thats why I keep saying. http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: @jamylak If you look at the URL, [:word:] is POSIX for [A-Za-z0-9_] which is alphanumeric and "_" and its shorhand equivalent is \w

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Unicode compliance, you need to use

```
regex = re.compile(r"[^\W\d_]", re.UNICODE)
```

Unicode character properties (like `\p{L}`) are not supported by the current Python regex engine.

**Explanation:**

`\w` matches (if the Unicode flag is set) any letter, digit or underscore.

`[^\W]` matches the same thing, but with the negated character class, we can now subtract characters we don't want included:

`[^\W\d_]` matches whatever `\w` matches, but without digits (`\d`) or underscore (`_`).

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"[^\W\d_]", re.UNICODE)
>>> regex.findall("aä12_")
['a', 'ä']
```

Answer (score -1):

Any character in the range:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

That is the best shorthand in Python for it..

Or you could do `[A-Z]` with `ignorecase`: `re.compile(r'[A-Z]', re.I)`

Or inline: `re.compile(r'(?i)[A-Z]')`

For unicode: `re.compile(r'[A-Z]', re.I|re.U)` or `re.compile(r'(?iu)[A-Z]')`

Comment: You probably want to add [`re.UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag as well, considering the question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: That's still not going to match more than just ASCII letters, then.

Comment: Unicode flag is utterly useless here. It only affects the shorthand character classes.